# Diablo 1 on Ubuntu 16.04 - Nostalgy

Tags: wine, games

I'd love to play Diablo 1 on Ubuntu.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi! I don't want to sound off-topic, but, if, for some reasons the bellow listed answers don't help you, maybe you should check on this project: https://freeablo.org/. Looks like some kind of open-source alternative to Diablo 1 which works on Linux too, so it spares you from the entire process of Wine installation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easily. Install wine and PlayOnLinux. Download the game, and use the Miscellaneous tab of playonlinux to run the exe.

The process could be as follows:

1. Install `playonlinux`:

   `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`

If the program can't be found in your software sources, download from here: [PlayOnLinux](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjp1pWyzOjTAhXGRCYKHUFBDC4QFggxMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.playonlinux.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGbgZxC5JIPptdNaRPeVTQHs0cK1g&sig2=JpE92svxespJuNmCbqOFAg)

2. Install `wine`:

   `sudo apt install wine`
3. Download the game
4. On PlayOnLinux, go to **Configure** -> **General** tab
5. In the left side panel, click on **New**, to create a new virtual disk.
6. Select the new created disk, and go to the **Miscellaneous** tab.
7. Click on **Run a .exe in this virtual drive**, and select the diablo installer.
8. Follow the installation program, and install it normally.
9. Once finished, go to the **General** tab, and click on **Make a new shortcut for this virtual drive**. Follow the instructions and search for the diablo executable.
10. Finish and close the **Configuration** window.
11. The diablo shortcut should appear in the main screen of PlayOnLinux, select it and click on Run.

Comment: When I try to run the game it loads as normal at first, and then the navbar pops up and it looks like the game loads, but I can only see a small portion of the game.

Answer (score 0):

some other solutions:

- install virtualbox - free `https://www.virtualbox.org/` or vmware player `http://www.vmware.com/`
- create a virtual xp machine, tutorials youtube `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJt6scJyDUw`
- install xp guest additions with 3d support from safemode `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EMvQqBCBqY`
- install game
- hf

be advised.. the mouse jumps uncontrollably sometimes especially if you scale the guest window; as a solution disable mouse integration and attach the mouse to virtual machine(you will be unable to take it outside of vm unless you disconnect it from the socket.. usb mouse)

- is helpful to have 2 mouses one attached to vm the other for host

edit: regarding vinehq.. be careful of infected programs.. thay can run as in windows and you cant jail windows apps to vinehq folder

obs: for vmware player.. youtube for tutorials.. i dont use it on linux as i prefer gpl/free/apt-repo programs; performance wise is close to virtualbox; i play lod/quake2/starcraft on virtualbox.. very fluent only problem is mouse bugs.. see workaround

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)